# How to get immediate value in commaseperated in c#

Tags: c#

```
string[] str = new string[] {"sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri","sat"};
```

If I pass Mon, then the result set should immediate value ie tue.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you going wrong? Assuming I'm reading your question right, there are a number of steps to solving that (possibly homework) problem (as well as a fundamental misunderstanding about "commaseparated[SIC]").

Answer (score 3):

If you are wanting to get the value immediately following, try this:

```
string sIn = "mon";
string[] str = new string[] {"sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"};
int current = Array.IndexOf(str, sIn);
int next = (current + 1) % str.Length;
string sOut = str[next];
return sOut;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if the array contains the input string.

```
string[] str = new string[] {"sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri","sat"};
public string NextDay(string day)
{
    string result = "";
    int index = Array.IndexOf(str, day);
    if(index > -1)
    {
        result = str[(index + 1) % str.Length];
    }
    else
    {
        result = "input is wrong";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

umm,  I assume your wanting to return the next value? if so something like this

```
public string GetNext(string input)
{
    string[] str = new string[] {"sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri","sat"};

    for(int I=0; I < str.length; I++)
    {
        if(str[I] == input)
        {
            return str[I+1];
        }
    }
}
```

you'd need some error checking if you wanted to wrap so that sat returned sun.  something like the following

```
public string GetNext(string input)
{
    string[] str = new string[] {"sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri","sat"};

    for(int I=0; I < str.length; I++)
    {
        if(str[I] == input)
        {
            if(I == str.length-1)
            {
                return str[0];
            } else {
                return str[I+1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if `input` is `sat`?

Comment: If input is "sat" then it will throw an exception, but you cannot expect folks to write your error handling and bounds checking for you as well.

Comment: Heh, well so much for my snarky comment.  There's your exception resistant code.

Comment: well no,  they could pass through a value that doesn't exist in my array in which case it falls over completely.  so I haven't fixed it completely. but meh,  the original question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Like This ,

```
string[] str = new string[] { "sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat" };    
var result = Array.FindIndex(str, element => element.Equals("mon", StringComparison.Ordinal));      

System.Console.WriteLine(result==-1 ? "not found" : str[result+1]);
```